# C# Get variable from popup form that will be closed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I have a form populated with an array of userControls that is created from the main form. I need to be able to access this array of userControls from the main form once the popup has been closed when a button is pressed. If I fill out the forms and then press the button on the main form without closing the popup, the values are present. However, if I close the popup window, the values are not present. My main form is static so I can use it's variables in other forms.

Code for the popup:

```
 public ScanChannel[] controls;
    public ScanListSetup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int numChans = Convert.ToInt32(Form1.Self.numChannels.Text);
        controls = new ScanChannel[numChans];

        // Create the UserControls
        for(int i = 0; i < numChans; i++)
        {
            controls[i] = new ScanChannel();
        }

        // Place them
        for (int i = 0; i < numChans; i++)
        {
            controls[i].Location = new Point(13,(35+25*(i)));
            this.Controls.Add(controls[i]);
        }

        doneButton.Location = new Point(82, 35 + (25 * (numChans + 1)));
        this.Size =new Size(280, 110 + (25 * (numChans + 1)));
    }

    private void doneButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.Self.setChannelsToScan(controls);
        }
```

I need to access the `controls` array in the main form. The code for the main form is as follows:

```
private ScanChannel[] channelsToScan;


private void configureScanListButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var form = new ScanListSetup();
        form.Show(this);
        scanListConfigured = true;
        this.channelsToScan = new ScanChannel[Convert.ToInt32(numChannels.Text)];

    }

public void setChannelsToScan(ScanChannel[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            this.channelsToScan[i] = arr[i];
        }
    }

 private void scanButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test: " + this.channelsToScan[0].getDeviceType());
        // THIS PRINTS AN EMPTY STRING
    }
```

So, the Debug writeLine outputs the correct value if I click the `scanButton` while the popup form is still open. However, if I close the form after clicking the `doneButton` on the popup form, the Debug writeLine outputs `Test:` with nothing else.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem essentially boils down to sending data from a secondary window (your 'pop-up' window) to the main window from where it was created. It doesn't matter whether you're working with Windows `Control` objects or simple data types like `string`, so I'm going to use a simple example to illustrate how to handle such a situation.

Let's assume you have a `Main` form that looks like this. It has an `OPEN` button and a `TextBox`.

[image]

When you click `OPEN`, it opens up this secondary input window (your pop-up) which looks like this:

[image]

Now the idea is this. You click `OPEN` and opens the `Input` form, and lets the user enter some text into the `TextBox` there. Once you click the `OK` button, it should close the `Input` window, and display the text entered by the user in the `Main` window. Remember that at this point the `Input` window is closed, which is equivalent to your situation.

So I'd make use of [Delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) to accomplish this goal. A `delegate` lets you transfer data between windows which is what you want.

In my `Main` I'd declare a `public` delegate with a signature like this:

```
public delegate void DataTransfer(string data);
```

That is, this `delegate` represents a method that takes in a single `string` parameter, and has `void` return type. The idea is to let the secondary `Input` window 'call' a method in the `Main`, and that method takes in a `string` parameter. So, if there was a way for us to call a method that resides in the `Main` from `Input`, and pass a `string`, we can then take the user input text in the `Input` window, and pass it to the `Main` window. With me so far?

Now, if I write a method like this in the `Main`, and let it be called from `Input`, that should accomplish our goal. Here, `txtDisplay` is the `TextBox` in the `Main` form.

```
public void ReceiveInput(string data)
{
    txtDisplay.Text = data;
}
```

To accomplish this, I would define a `delegate` of type `DataTransfer` in the `Main` form like below, and register the `ReceiveInput()` method to it. Your `Main` form code behind should look like this:

```
public delegate void DataTransfer(string data);

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public DataTransfer transferDelegate;

    InputForm inputForm = null;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        transferDelegate += new DataTransfer(ReceiveInput);
    }

    public void ReceiveInput(string data)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = data;
    }

    private void BtnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        inputForm = new InputForm(transferDelegate);
        inputForm.Show();
    }
}
```

`BtnOpen` is the `OPEN` button in the `Main` form, and when it's clicked, it passes the delegate to the `Input` form, then opens it. So, accordingly, we need to now modify our `Input` form:

```
public partial class InputForm : Form
{
    DataTransfer transferDel;

    public InputForm(DataTransfer del)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        transferDel = del;
    }

    private void BtnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string data = txtInput.Text;
        transferDel.Invoke(data);
        Close();
    }
}
```

Here, we modify the constructor so that it takes in a `delegate` of type `DataTransfer`, and sets it to the local instance of the same type. Then, at the click of `BtnOK` on the `Input` form, we take in the text input by user, and pass that text to the said `delegate` and invoke it. 'Invoking' is the same as calling the method in the `Main` form. At this point, you can `Clsoe()` the `Input` window as shown above, and you'd still have access to the user input `string` data from your `Main` form.

You can use this same approach, and instead of strings you can pass around `Controls`. However, it's not the best approach to pass around a bunch of controls back and forth, so ideally you would extract the data you need from those controls in your pop-up, and pass only the said data instead of the whole controls.

---

**EDIT: After OP posted the erroneous code.**

OK, so here's your issue. The `testUserControl` class is not a regular class but a control element derived from `UserControl`. In otherwise, a GUI element. You shouldn't use GUI elements to pass data around. Because, when you do your `controlArr[i].getText();`, it tries to get the text from the `textItem`, but `textItem` is a `TextBox` Control ***which doesn't exist at this point*** because you closed your window. Remember, you do the `delegate.Invoke()` only once, and at that point **you must send ALL the data back to your main window**.

What you should do is, simply define a class to hold ALL the data you want to pass to your main. For example something like this:

```
public class DataToPass
{
    public string TextBoxText { get; set; }

    public string SomeOtherData { get; set; }

    // Other stuff you want...
}
```

Now, instead of passing an array of `testUserControl`, pass an array of `DataToPass`. That way, at the `Main` form you don't have to do the following:

```
controlArr[i].getText();
```

Instead you'd simply do something like:

```
controlArr[i].TextBoxText;
```

where `controlArr` now is an array of type `DataToPass`.

Simply, passing a control derived from `UserControl` is not a good idea. Just create one class that is capable of holding ALL the data you want to pass and pass it back to the main once.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I am still having the same problem after trying this. If I remove the `Close()` and keep the popup window open, my main form can access the data. If I close the popup, it's blank. I checked and the `ReceiveData` function is being called, but it's like once the popup window is gone, it; for the lack of a better term, dereferences the variable in my main. Sorry if I didn't explain the issue very well. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Perhaps share your code, you can upload it to github. Because this should work, before closing your popup you call the method and pass the value to `Main`, and it doesn't matter if the popup is open or closed at that point.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to post my code as per company policy. Do you think the problem may be because in C# arrays are reference types? So by deleting the popup form, I am deleting the array that is being referenced to. If I just send a string instead of an array, it works fine.

Comment: I simply can't debug a code I can't see. If you can't share code as per company policy, what people often do is create a mock code sample that replicates the issue without sharing actual code.

Comment: One possiblity is though that when you do something like `some_array = another_array;` in C#, it creates a reference. So when original data is gone so is duplicate data. If you're doing something like that, try `some_array = another_array.ToArray();`

Comment: https://github.com/hosfordryan/PersonalProjects/tree/master/popupBugFixing Here is a link to a recreation of my problem. Thanks for the help.